# Multi-precision linear programming solver in C++

Tags: solver

I'm implementing some algorithms in C++ and I need to solve some linear programs as an intermediate step within the algorithm.

I've managed to get the `linear_solver` from [google or-ools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) working, as well as [glpk](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/).

My issue is that I need to work with and solve LPs with very high precision integer types - more than 256 bits - in order for the algorithm to be correct (it's complicated but the algorithm can give very incorrect answers if less precision is used). At the moment I'm using `mpz_class` and `mpf_class` from [gmp](https://gmplib.org/) to store my numbers.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your question, but just wanted to mention that although increased precision has its uses, we typically don't see as much benefit as one might expect - it will give you a handful more orders of magnitude of correct calculations and that's it. Mileage may very, but people are typically far better off reformulating the problem, trying to scale it well, and/or using a solver with good numerics.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5167/is-there-a-linear-programming-library-that-natively-supports-fractions-instead-o/5177#5177). The answers reference a number of exact solvers. I don't know if any solver supports higher but limited precision instead of exact.

GLPK itself supports exact arithmetic. It may be more difficult to use from the C++ interface than the command line, but [is documented in the API](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Using_the_GLPK_callable_library).

Answer (score 0):

The [Soplex solver](https://soplex.zib.de/) is a simplex-based LP solver, available as a C++ library. It supports regular (double precision) input, quad precision computation, and can provide exact solutions using iterative refinement and rational exact arithmetic.

While I have never used it myself directly, it is the default LP solver in SCIP. I would recommend checking the documentation to see how you can use the higher-precision functionality.